# Error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting the this error: **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass** when trying to render **choose_album_to_add.html.erb** :

```
<table class="table_">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Album</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @albums.each do |album| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= album.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

my **users_controller.rb**

```
def choose_album_to_add
       @albums = Album.all
end
```

What could be wrong?
**Edit**

As asked, I'm sure that my view file choose_album_to_add.html.erb is in /app/views/users .
And I've a route like this:

match '/addAlbum/:id', to: 'users#choose_album_to_add', via: 'get'

Of course, I'm typing /addAlbum/45 on Browser, and it routes properly. The view is also loaded for sure, but the problem is that the instance vars that I declared on my controller can't be accessed on my view . =[

I've scaffolded four resources and they're working fine following this conventions of declaring instance variables and using then in views. I know there are alternative ways ( like passings locals ) but I want to do the job this way.

The log from the console when tryng to access

```
Started GET "/addAlbum/50" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-24 09:56:13 -0400
Processing by UsersController#choose_album_to_add as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"50"}
  Rendered users/choose_album_to_add.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    14:   </thead>
    15: 
    16:   <tbody>
    17:     <% @albums.each do |album| %>
    18:       <tr>
    19:         <td><%= album.name %></td>
    20:         <td><%= album.created_on %></td>
  app/views/users/choose_album_to_add.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_users_choose_album_to_add_html_erb___3017203676622264637_69974786999340'
```

When I run Album.all on Console I get:

```
SELECT "albums".* FROM "albums"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Album id: 1, name: "Album1", created_on: "2014-03-17 23:33:00", finishes_on: "2014-03-24 13:16:00", created_at: "2014-03-17 23:33:14", updated_at: "2014-03-24 13:16:32">, #<Album id: 2, name: "Album2", created_on: "2014-03-17 23:33:00", finishes_on: "2014-03-24 13:16:00", created_at: "2014-03-17 23:33:28", updated_at: "2014-03-24 13:16:42">]>
```

which is my two tuples that I inserted via the Rest methods generated by scaffold.

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.photographer_id = session[:current_photographer_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Novo usuário cadastrado com sucesso. Um email foi encaminhado a ele contendo as informações de acesso.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Dados atualizados com sucesso' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :endereco, :telefone, :cpf)
    end

    def choose_album_to_add
       @albums = Album.all
    end

  end
end
```

Any appointments more? Thanks

Comment: what does rails console output when you execute `Album.all` ?

Comment: Can you show us your routes please ?

Comment: @vee that does not explain why `@albums` is nil. It should just be empty

Comment: @Oxynum, true.  `Album.all` should return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.  Thanks for the correction.  In that case, I hope this is not a typo issue.

Comment: Can you confirm `choose_album_to_add.html.erb` is in the directory `app/views/users`?

Comment: Are you using Rails 4.1.0rc1 version?

Comment: @KirtiThorat I'm using 4.0.3

Comment: @GraemeMcLean Yes, for sure.

Comment: Can you share the generated server log when you visit `/addAlbum/45`

Comment: @Pavarine Go on `rails console`. Run `Album.all` and share the output.

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger to check what's happening when you assign `@albums` in `def choose_album_to_add`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat know what u guys are thinking, but if I change my code to '@albums = 1 '( or anything else ) I still can't access it on my view..so I think the problem is not the Album model itself.

Comment: `@albums = 1` will just set @albums to an integer value. Can you share  the results of `Album.all` from `rails console`.

Comment: Of course I can :) @KirtiThorat

Comment: @Pavarine Share the full content of the view `choose_album_to_add`.

Comment: Could you also share your whole users controller please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method `def choose_album_to_add` is private - move the definition above the `private` statement.

Since `choose_album_to_add` is an action is has to be a public method to be used by the view.  I think you already proved the method wasn't being called when you tried to set `@albums = 1` and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Glad we found it - it's been annoying me (and you too I imagine) all day!

Comment: I get this error DESPITE no private methods having been defined in my controller in Rails 5.0.  This is really bad (aggravating).  Rails is behaving in direct contradiction to its own documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Is really choose_album_to_add being called when loading the view? (and so, the @album var) As some said in previous comments, if the problem was an empty table it should return an empty array/active_relation.

Another way to have that collection is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    helper_method :albums

    private
    def albums
        @albums ||= Album.all
    end
end
```

Then in your view just call album.each instead of @album.each